# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I have some JavaScript code that gives this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Here is my code:

```
var i1 = document.getElementById('i1');
var i2 = document.getElementById('i2');
var __i = {'user' : document.getElementsByName("username")[0], 'pass' : document.getElementsByName("password")[0] };
if(  __i.user.value.length >= 1 ) { i1.value = ''; } else { i1.value = 'Acc'; }

if(  __i.pass.value.length >= 1 ) { i2.value = ''; } else { i2.value = 'Pwd'; }
```

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Seems like one of your values, with a property key of 'value' is undefined. Test that `i1`, `i2`and `__i` are defined before executing the if statements:

```
var i1 = document.getElementById('i1');
var i2 = document.getElementById('i2');
var __i = {'user' : document.getElementsByName("username")[0], 'pass' : document.getElementsByName("password")[0] };
if(i1 && i2 && __i.user && __i.pass)
{
    if(  __i.user.value.length >= 1 ) { i1.value = ''; } else { i1.value = 'Acc'; }

    if(  __i.pass.value.length >= 1 ) { i2.value = ''; } else { i2.value = 'Pwd'; }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Either `document.getElementById('i1')`, `document.getElementById('i2')`, or `document.getElementsByName("username")[0]` is returning no element. Check, that all elements exist.

Comment: thanks... i forget that when user is logged in , there is no input named username or password... i have added if statement ' if(i2 && i2) ' and it works.. sometimes easiest code may get you in trouble :D

Answer (score 10):

Try this, It always works, and you will get NO TypeError:

```
try{

    var i1 = document.getElementById('i1');
    var i2 = document.getElementById('i2');
    var __i = {'user' : document.getElementsByName("username")[0], 'pass' : document.getElementsByName("password")[0] };
    if(  __i.user.value.length >= 1 ) { i1.value = ''; } else { i1.value = 'Acc'; }
    if(  __i.pass.value.length >= 1 ) { i2.value = ''; } else { i2.value = 'Pwd'; }

}catch(e){
    if(e){
    // If fails, Do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for showing the proper way of doing this. Althought I'm curious why the `if(e)` needs to be inside `catch(e)` since it already caught the `(e)`

Comment: @TetraDev 'e' will return 'undefined' unless it's a valid TypeError. So you validate the TypeError in the 'if' statement and you can also execute custom TypeErrors.

Comment: simple and great :)

Comment: You get no TypeError, nor any other errors, because you've caught them all and swallowed them. The least you could do is check what the error is and rethrow if you don't know.

Answer (score 6):

First, you should make sure that document.getElementsByName("username")[0] actually returns an object and not "undefined". You can simply check like

```
if (typeof document.getElementsByName("username")[0] != 'undefined')
```

Similarly for the other element password.

Answer (score 6):

The posts here help me a lot on my way to find a solution for the **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined** issue.

There are already here many answers which are correct, but what we don't have here is the combination for 2 answers that i think resolve this issue completely.

```
function myFunction(field, data){
  if (typeof document.getElementsByName("+field+")[0] != 'undefined'){
  document.getElementsByName("+field+")[0].value=data;
 }
}
```

The difference is that you make a check(if a property is defined or not) and if the check is true then you can try to assign it a value.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a function to check if the variable exists, else will return a default value :

```
function isSet(element, defaultVal){

    if(typeof element != 'undefined'){

        return element;

    }

    console.log('one missing element');

    return defaultVal;
}
```

And use it in a variable check:

```
var variable = isSet(variable, 'Default value');
```

Answer (score 0):

You code looks like automatically generated from other code - you should check that html elements with `id=i1` and `i2` and `name=username` and `password` exists before processing them.