# Bootstrap DatePicker check in/check out

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

This should be straight forward... but after 2 hours I still can't see the problem.

I'm trying to implement two datepickers "Check In" / "Check Out" with the [eternicode datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker).

The author himself even documents the updated solution that works with his version [here](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/535#issuecomment-20976860).

```
var nowTemp = new Date();
var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

var checkin = $('#dpd1').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        return date.valueOf() >= now.valueOf();
    }
}).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
        var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
        checkout.setValue(newDate);
        checkout.setDate(newDate);
        checkout.update();
    }
    checkin.hide();
    $('#dpd2')[0].focus();
}).data('datepicker');
var checkout = $('#dpd2').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        return date.valueOf() > checkin.date.valueOf();
    }
}).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    checkout.hide();
}).data('datepicker');
```

When I try and implement it, I get the following in my console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'valueOf' of undefined
```

I've tried to define the date variable however it doesn't appear to make a difference.

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/56bVc/1/

Looking forward to your help but not looking forward to the forehead slap thats going to come with it!

Comment: Try changing `chackin.date` to `checkin.dates[0]` and `checkout.date` to `checkout.dates[0]`

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question. I also had the same issue when using this https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker version of the datepicker.

After a few headaches, I have recoded some of the check in / check out scripts with some success.

Hope this helps others with facing the same issue.

```js
var nowTemp = new Date();
var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

var checkin = $('#dpd1').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
    }
}).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.viewDate.valueOf()){
        var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
        checkout.setDate(newDate);  
    }
    else {
        checkout.setDate(ev.date + 1);
    }
    
    checkin.hide();
    $('#dpd2')[0].focus();
}).data('datepicker');

var checkout = $('#dpd2').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        return date.valueOf() <= checkin.viewDate.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
    }
}).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    checkout.hide();
}).data('datepicker');
```

Answer (score 0):

I read some blog and as per my understanding this is the issue of jquery reference or your variable is not define before you use.

Good thing is check first your jquery,jquery ui & all js are loaded , then check the variable with alert .

Or you can remove your variable reference and then check that the issue is not from another variable.

[Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550795/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-value-of-undefined)

http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?1102772-Uncaught-TypeError-Cannot-read-property-value-of-null

Comment: Thanks, but I have already come across both those pages in my research before i posted this question.

Comment: Good Dear, I just give some basic idea to rectify about this error. The error show that the variable is not define. You do one thing. Just check before use like > If(typeof variablename == "undefined") return;

Comment: Correct, and no matter how often I define the variables it remains undefined... so I think there is a deeper issue.

Answer (score 0):

What Bootstrap version do you use? Looking through the plugin's code, it uses Bootstrap class names for picking the elements from the DOM (there are versions for BS3 and BS2).

You may also want to provide your HTML markup to verify it's according to the right format.

Comment: Hello, If you want to see the HTML markup check out the JS fiddle in the question.