# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I have problem with select tag. I google it and didn't find any solution regarding my question. here is one of the link... ([Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550795/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-value-of-undefined))..... I have function on onchange event in the select tag some how like this..

```
           <select id="selectBox" onchange="_change();">
                    <?php
                    $i = 1;
                    while ($lastpage >= $i):?>
                    <option><?php echo $i; ?></option>
                        <?php
                        $i++;
                    endwhile;
                    ?>
          </select>
```

Possible jQuery code ...

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     function _change(evt)
        {
            alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
        };
    </script>
```

The question is Why I am getting undefined of undefined  instead getting  a value or property undefined so that I can go ahead and solve that prob...
Thanks any help would more be appreciated...

Comment: The first step would be to remove the superfluous `</a>` from your server-side code.

Comment: sorry it isn't present in the code but mistakenly added here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the referrer element `this` to your javascript function.

Code:

```
<select id="selectBox" onchange="_change(this);">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

js:

```
function _change(el) {
   alert(el.options[el.selectedIndex].value);
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g5hzph1y/

Answer (score 0):

```
***SIMPLEST REPRESENTATION:-***    

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    Select a fruit and click the button:
    <select id="mySelect">
      <option value="11">Apple</option>
      <option value="12">Orange</option>
      <option value="13">Pineapple</option>
      <option value="14">Banana</option>
    </select>

    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Display index</button>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;
        var y = document.getElementById("mySelect").options;
        alert("Index: " + y[x].index + " text is " + y[x].text + " and value is " +  y[x].value);
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```