# TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror

When I try to click on **Search from documents** element it returns error in console.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

```
$('.js-main-search').data('uiAutocomplete')._renderMenu = function (ul, items) {
  var branchesResults = true;
  var companiesResults = true;
  var currentCategory = '';
  var that = this;
  ul.append('<li class="search-documents-btn">Search from documents &raquo;</li>');
  // ...
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550795/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-value-of-undefined)

Comment: Can you locate which line the error occurs? The first or last?

Comment: I don't see anywhere here that you are trying to access a value property. It seems as though the code you have posted isn't your problem. Could post a jsFiddle that reproduces the issue you are seeing?