# JavaScript error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a script to remove uploaded files after Add to success, but I get this error on site when it loads.

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined"
```

What's missing?

```
<script>
onload=function() {
    document.querySelectorAll("li[id^='uploadNameSpan']")[0].remove();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Should it not be window.onload ???

Comment: @David This is the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550795/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-value-of-undefined)

Comment: Nothing matches your selector pattern.

Comment: Either the selector is wrong...or elements are added after code runs. If it's the latter need to show how they get added. All the explanations why it fails don't get you to solution to make it work

Comment: Anyway, check your HTML and selector and then read about removeChild method.

Comment: based on the name it might be that the id is in a span tag and not in a list item

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically, your issue is that, at the time you call this code, you don't have any elements in the DOM corresponding to the query `"li[id^='uploadNameSpan']"`. So `querySelectorAll` returns an empty [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) which has `undefined` at the `0` position (or any position for that matter).

Breakdown of what is happening:

```
var liElements = document.querySelectorAll("li[id^='uploadNameSpan']"); // this returns an empty NodeList

var nonExistentFirstElement = liElements[0]; // this is undefined, there's nothing at the first position

nonExistentFirstElement.remove(); // thus, this is an error since you're calling `undefined.remove()`
```

Depending on your use case, one thing you can do is have a check for the amount of items returned before trying to remove:

```
var liElements = document.querySelectorAll("li[id^='uploadNameSpan']");
if (liElements.length > 0) {
  liElements[0].remove();
}
```

In general, you have to make sure to have the element in the DOM at the time you are trying to remove it.

Comment: `this returns []` not really accurate ... is elementList not array

Comment: @charlietfl its array-like and irrelevant for this particular problem but you're right. I've actually written that down first and then edited the question to simplify it. Switched it back now.

Comment: This seems to work perfect. No script error and functions like it should. Thank you so much

Comment: for me, I had to use if( liElements != null ) instead of if(liElements.length > 0)

Comment: @PrabuddhaKulatunga that's likely because you used `querySelector` instead of `querySelectorAll`