# TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined at updateUserList (<MY_PATH>\chatapp\socket\socket.js:34:29)

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am not able to get username & userPic all connected room users.

please suggest me how can I fix it ? please help ~

```
<MY_PATH>\chatapp\socket\socket.js:34
            user:getUsers[i].username,
                            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
    at updateUserList (<MY_PATH>\chatapp\socket\socket.js:34:29)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (<MY_PATH>\chatapp\socket\socket.js:22:7)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at <MY_PATH>\chatapp\node_modules\socket.io\lib\socket.js:514:12
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

This is the code.

```
function updateUserList(room, updateALL){
      var getUsers = io.of('/messages').in(room).clients();
      var userlist = [];
      for(var i in getUsers){
        userlist.push({
            user:getUsers[i].username,
            userPic:getUsers[i].userPic
          });
      }
      socket.to(room).emit('updateUsersList', JSON.stringify(userlist));

      if(updateALL) {
        socket.broadcast.to(room).emit('updateUsersList')
      }

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550795/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-value-of-undefined)

Comment: What do you get if you log **getUsers** to the console?

Comment: Namespace {
  name: '/messages',
  server:
  connected:
   { '/messages#g3ylC0osj4SFJlkSAAAC':
      Socket {
        
        username: 'Virendra Kumar',
        userPic: 'https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/21078271_1452824561450709_6824442799108958435_n.jpg?oh=38e9461d2dde855c01e085b5ae2f9681&amp;oe=5A7C1B0F' } },

Comment: please provide us a more code i.e where is your function() updateUserList(room, updateALL)  {} get's executed provide with your server configuration

Comment: Hi, I am attached our server.js code and getUsers  response in answer please see below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am getting data in getUsers as following:

```
Namespace {
  name: '/messages',
  server:
   Server {
     nsps: { '/': [Object], '/roomlist': [Object], '/messages': [Object] },
     _path: '/socket.io',
     _serveClient: true,
     parser:
      { protocol: 4,
        types: [Array],
        CONNECT: 0,
        DISCONNECT: 1,
        EVENT: 2,
        ACK: 3,
        ERROR: 4,
        BINARY_EVENT: 5,
        BINARY_ACK: 6,
        Encoder: [Function: Encoder],
        Decoder: [Function: Decoder] },
     encoder: Encoder {},
     _adapter: [Function: Adapter],
     _origins: '*:*',
     sockets:
      Namespace {
        name: '/',
        server: [Object],
        sockets: [Object],
        connected: [Object],
        fns: [],
        ids: 0,
        rooms: [],
        flags: {},
        adapter: [Object] },
     eio:
      Server {
        clients: [Object],
        clientsCount: 1,
        wsEngine: 'ws',
        pingTimeout: 60000,
        pingInterval: 25000,
        upgradeTimeout: 10000,
        maxHttpBufferSize: 100000000,
        transports: [Array],
        allowUpgrades: true,
        allowRequest: [Function: bound ],
        cookie: 'io',
        cookiePath: '/',
        cookieHttpOnly: true,
        perMessageDeflate: [Object],
        httpCompression: [Object],
        initialPacket: [Array],
        ws: [Object],
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1 },
     httpServer:
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 5,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 3,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        _connectionKey: '6::::3000',
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 13 },
     engine:
      Server {
        clients: [Object],
        clientsCount: 1,
        wsEngine: 'ws',
        pingTimeout: 60000,
        pingInterval: 25000,
        upgradeTimeout: 10000,
        maxHttpBufferSize: 100000000,
        transports: [Array],
        allowUpgrades: true,
        allowRequest: [Function: bound ],
        cookie: 'io',
        cookiePath: '/',
        cookieHttpOnly: true,
        perMessageDeflate: [Object],
        httpCompression: [Object],
        initialPacket: [Array],
        ws: [Object],
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1 } },
  sockets:
   { '/messages#g3ylC0osj4SFJlkSAAAC':
      Socket {
        nsp: [Object],
        server: [Object],
        adapter: [Object],
        id: '/messages#g3ylC0osj4SFJlkSAAAC',
        client: [Object],
        conn: [Object],
        rooms: [Object],
        acks: {},
        connected: true,
        disconnected: false,
        handshake: [Object],
        fns: [],
        flags: {},
        _rooms: [],
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 3,
        username: 'Virendra Kumar',
        userPic: 'https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/21078271_1452824561450709_6824442799108958435_n.jpg?oh=38e9461d2dde855c01e085b5ae2f9681&amp;oe=5A7C1B0F' } },
  connected:
   { '/messages#g3ylC0osj4SFJlkSAAAC':
      Socket {
        nsp: [Object],
        server: [Object],
        adapter: [Object],
        id: '/messages#g3ylC0osj4SFJlkSAAAC',
        client: [Object],
        conn: [Object],
        rooms: [Object],
        acks: {},
        connected: true,
        disconnected: false,
        handshake: [Object],
        fns: [],
        flags: {},
        _rooms: [],
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 3,
        username: 'Virendra Kumar',
        userPic: 'https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/2799108958435_n.jpg?oh=38e9461d2dde855c01e085b5ae2f9681&amp;oe=5A7C1B0F' } },
  fns: [],
  ids: 0,
  rooms: [],
  flags: {},
  adapter:
   Adapter {
     nsp: [Circular],
     rooms: { '8229': [Object], '/messages#g3ylC0osj4SFJlkSAAAC': [Object] },
     sids: { '/messages#g3ylC0osj4SFJlkSAAAC': [Object] },
     encoder: Encoder {} },
  _events: { connection: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is server.js code:

```
module.exports = function(io, rooms){

  // Establish the connection
  var chatrooms = io.of('/roomlist').on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('Connection Establish on the server!');
    socket.emit('roomupdate', JSON.stringify(rooms)); // sends it back to the user that created it in the first place.

    // Receive the new room event.
    socket.on('newroom', function(data){
      rooms.push(data); // append the data into the array.
      socket.broadcast.emit('roomupdate', JSON.stringify(rooms)); // doesn't broadcast to the person that created the room.
      socket.emit('roomupdate', JSON.stringify(rooms)); // sends it back to the user that created it in the first place.
    })
  });

  var messages = io.of('/messages').on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('Connected to the Chatroom!');
    socket.on('joinroom', function(data){
      socket.username = data.user;
      socket.userPic = data.userPic;
      socket.join(data.room); //push user into partitioned room.
      updateUserList(data.room, true);
    });

    socket.on('newMessage', function(data){
      socket.broadcast.to(data.room_number).emit('messagefeed', JSON.stringify(data));
    });

     function updateUserList(room, updateALL){
      var getUsers = io.of('/messages').in(room).clients();
      //console.log(getUsers);return false;
      var userlist = [];
      for(var i in getUsers){
        userlist.push({
            user:getUsers[i].username,
            userPic:getUsers[i].userPic
          });
      }
      socket.to(room).emit('updateUsersList', JSON.stringify(userlist));

      if(updateALL) {
        socket.broadcast.to(room).emit('updateUsersList')
      }

    }

    socket.on('updateList', function(data){
      updateUserList(data.room);
    })

  });

}
```