# Getting information before Component is rendered but cannot use getInitialProps ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, web3js

I have some code below. I need to get information via a call after web3 is injected by metamask but just before it renders but I cannot use getInitialProps as it will fail because of server side rendering. Not really sure how to design this.

```
class CampaignIndex extends Component {

async componentDidMount() {
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    const campaigns = await factory.methods
    .getCampaigns("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", 0)
    .call({
        from: accounts[0]
    });
    
    console.log(campaigns["completedCampaigns"]);
    console.log(campaigns["ongoingCampaigns"]);

    return { campaigns };
}

render() {
    return <div>{this.props.campaigns["completedCampaigns"][0]}</div>
 }
}

export default CampaignIndex;
```

> Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'completedCampaigns' of undefined

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550795/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-value-of-undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think its better to use `setState`. The way you use `props` in not the proper way to use them.

```
async componentDidMount() {
 const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
 const campaigns = await factory.methods
 .getCampaigns("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", 0)
 .call({
    from: accounts[0]
 });

 console.log(campaigns["completedCampaigns"]);
 console.log(campaigns["ongoingCampaigns"]);

 this.setState({
   campaigns:campaigns
 })
}

render() {
 return <div>{this.state.campaigns["completedCampaigns"][0]}</div>
}
```