# How to pass the function of a parsed ABI to MetaMask?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js, metamask

I am developing a dApp that is parsing an ABI and then it shows the functions of it and fields that is for every function's variable and i want to send the function with its variables to MetaMask to make the transaction.

I have a client-side web dApp written in web3js.

```js
const fntype = document.getElementById("function-name").value;
console.log(fntype);

  //Counter of Variables
  
var counter = $('.validate').length

var NumOfValidates = counter-1;

console.log(NumOfValidates);

console.log("--------------------");

  //A JS array that it will be filled with all the inputs the user give for each function's variable in order
  
var variables = [];
  
var id = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < NumOfValidates; ++i) {
      
id = id+1;
     
 variables.push(document.getElementById("i"+id).value);
     
 console.log("variable["+i+"] = "+variables[i]);
     
 console.log("--------------------");
 
 }
     
//SendToMetaMask

 miniToken.fntype(variables[1],{ from: address, value: '0'})
 
 .then(function (txHash) {

  console.log('Transaction sent')
 
 console.dir(txHash)

  waitForTxToBeMined(txHash)
}
```

Expected: Pass the function to MetaMask to complete the transaction

Actual: I get the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fntype' of undefined
>
> at senddata2 (script.js:234)
>
> at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick ((index):110)
>
> senddata2 @ script.js:234
>
> onclick @ (index):110

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550795/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-value-of-undefined)

Answer (score 1):

The contract is not initialized correctly. hence the error:

> Cannot read property 'fntype' of undefined`

```
var miniToken = web3.eth.Contract(abi, address) //web3js@1.0
var miniToken = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(address) //web3js@0.20
```

After this you can do

```
miniToken.fntype(variables[1],{ from: address, value: '0'})
```

Comment: I am declaring the miniToken in a function startApp with the way you show me dear friend. I tried both of them.