# TypeError: logging.log is not a function JavaScript Google Cloud Fuction

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions

I have searched and can not find anything on this issue.

I have deployed a few Google Cloud functions written in JavaScript which  leverages the following function to report errors. The functions run successfully but I have been receiving the following error:

> TypeError: logging.log is not a function
>       at reportError (/user_code/index.js:158:23)

```
const logging = require('@google-cloud/logging');
```

reportError function:

```
function reportError(err, context = {}) {

  const logName = 'errors';
  const log = logging.log(logName);

  // https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/ref_v2beta1/rest/v2beta1/MonitoredResource
  const metadata = {
    resource: {
      type: 'cloud_function',
      labels: {function_name: process.env.FUNCTION_NAME},
    },
  };

  // https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/reference/rest/v1beta1/ErrorEvent
  const errorEvent = {
    message: err.stack,
    serviceContext: {
      service: process.env.FUNCTION_NAME,
      resourceType: 'cloud_function',
    },
    context: context,
  };

  // Write the error log entry
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    log.write(log.entry(metadata, errorEvent), (error) => {
      if (error) {
       return reject(error);
      }
      return resolve();
    });
  });
}
// [END reporterror]
```

Comment: For starters, you should provide more context on how the 'logging' variable was initialized.

Comment: apologies - i've updated my question above.

Answer (score 3):

As it stands, by changing the initialization of the 'logging' variable to, replacing YOUR_PROJECT_ID with the project id where these Cloud Function was created:

```
const logging = new (require('@googlecloud/logging')).Logging({projectId:'YOUR_PROJECT_ID'});
```

It should work.

You can change the code in multiple ways, but based on what you posted here would be the new version (just edit the projectId variable accordingly):

```
const google_cloud_logging = require('@google-cloud/logging');

function reportError(err, context = {}) {

  const logName = 'errors';

  const projectId = '';

  const logging = new google_cloud_logging.Logging({projectId: projectId});

  const log = logging.log(logName);

  // https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/ref_v2beta1/rest/v2beta1/MonitoredResource
  const metadata = {
    resource: {
      type: 'cloud_function',
      labels: {function_name: process.env.FUNCTION_NAME},
    },
  };

  // https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/reference/rest/v1beta1/ErrorEvent
  const errorEvent = {
    message: err.stack,
    serviceContext: {
      service: process.env.FUNCTION_NAME,
      resourceType: 'cloud_function',
    },
    context: context,
  };

  // Write the error log entry
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    log.write(log.entry(metadata, errorEvent), (error) => {
      if (error) {
       return reject(error);
      }
      return resolve();
    });
  });
}
// [END reporterror]
```

This changes were based on the [following example](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-logging#readme).

Comment: Your first suggestion gave me `Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module '@googlecloud/logging'` even though I can see `"@google-cloud/logging": "^0.7.1"` listed in my `package.json` file under dependencies. You second suggestion deployed successfully but when it's triggered I get two log errors 1. `(node:2) DeprecationWarning: grpc.load: Use the @grpc/proto-loader module with grpc.loadPackageDefinition instead`, also 2. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'stack' of undefined at reportError...`

Comment: I believe you can ignore the 'DeprecationWarning'. The error you could also got it from this piece of code ‘function f(a) {a.c;};f()’. So you might be calling the function 'reportError' with no arguments. Check the following link for more education on the subject: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550795/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-value-of-undefined.

Comment: I was getting the same error, and the second solution above worked