# How to fix "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'number' of undefined"?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I just picked up JavaScript this month and I'm trying to understand the `forEach` method along with the `data-set` idea to print the custom `data-set` (`data-number`) for each of the items in the array on the console. So when I click the button, it shows the `data-number`s for each of the array items (div-elements) on the console.

It keeps returning the error

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'number' of undefined", even when I've assigned number a value.

I notice that when I use just one div element and remove the "`Array.from`" it prints the `data-number` for that one element on the console, with no errors.

Could it be a syntax problem, or something I'm missing?

```js
myDiv = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('myDiv'));

function myFunction() {

  const number = myDiv.dataset["number"];
  console.log(number);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> Datasets</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="myDiv" data-name="MrMr" data-number="1">
    THIS IS A TEXT
  </div>

  <div class="myDiv" data-number="2">
    another text.
  </div>

  <div class="myDiv" data-number="3">
    another text.
  </div>

  <div class="myDiv" data-number="4">
    another text.
  </div>


  <p id="demo"></p>
  <button onclick="myDiv.forEach(myFunction());">Button</button>


  <script>
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I'm hoping to get a simple array that shows the data-sets I've saved in the div tags (i.e 1, 2, 3, 4).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550795/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-value-of-undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things - don't use `forEach()`, and use `map()` in your `myFunction`:

```js
 

myDiv = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('myDiv'));

function myFunction(){

    const number = myDiv.map(d => d.dataset["number"]);
    console.log(number);
}
```

```html
 

<div class="myDiv" data-name="MrMr" data-number="1">
THIS IS A TEXT
</div>

<div class="myDiv" data-number="2">
another text.
</div>

<div class="myDiv" data-number="3">
another text.
</div>

<div class="myDiv" data-number="4">
another text.
</div>


<p id="demo"></p>
<button onclick="myFunction();">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like so:

```js
var myFancyButton = document.querySelector('.myFancyButton'); // get the button via querySelector("className")

myFancyButton.addEventListener('click', function() { // add a click event listener to the button
    var myDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.myDiv'); // query for alle elements with a class name = "myDiv"
    myDivs.forEach(function(myDiv) { // now use forEach on all those divs
        const number = myDiv.dataset["number"];
        console.log(number);
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="myDiv" data-name="MrMr" data-number="1">
    THIS IS A TEXT
</div>

<div class="myDiv" data-number="2">
    another text.
</div>

<div class="myDiv" data-number="3">
    another text.
</div>

<div class="myDiv" data-number="4">
    another text.
</div>


<p id="demo"></p>
<button class="myFancyButton">Button</button>
```

Comment: Yes, but OP is clearly a beginner, so an explanation might be in order.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca thank you, added some comments in the code

Answer (score 0):

First - the function you want array.forEach() to execute needs an element to process. In your case these are the individual DIV elements. So you're function needs a parameter that 'links' to that particular element.
This can be done like:

```
function myFunction(element);
```

The attribute you want to query is called **data-number**, so I'd recommend using it. If you want to get a specific property of a DOM element, you can use `element.getAttribute(attribute);`
Here's a complete example:

```js
    myDiv = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('myDiv'));

    function myFunction(element) {

      var theNumber = element.getAttribute("data-number");

      console.log(theNumber);
    }

    myDiv.forEach(myFunction);
```

```html
<div class="myDiv" data-name="MrMr" data-number="1">
  THIS IS A TEXT
</div>

<div class="myDiv" data-number="2">
  another text.
</div>

<div class="myDiv" data-number="3">
  another text.
</div>

<div class="myDiv" data-number="4">
  another text.
</div>
```