# matplotlib numpy -- TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined -- Graph not showing up?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, pytorch

This code works on one machine, but not the other. I can't seem to isolate the issue with the dependencies.

Sample code from: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/simple_plot.html

--

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Data for plotting
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, s)

ax.set(xlabel='time (s)', ylabel='voltage (mV)',
       title='About as simple as it gets, folks')
ax.grid()

fig.savefig("test.png")
plt.show()
```

**--> TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined**

This code does not produce a stack trace of explicitly fail. The TypeError: is returned by the call to plt.show(). I tried searching for this error, but I couldn't find anything reported. (I added a screenshot of what visual-studio on the server I am working on shows. I will likely just create a docker of my other environment as I should have done that in the first place to avoid having my configuration break.) The graph saves correctly to file. It's just an issue with plt.show().

np.**version**
'1.17.2'

matplotlib.**version**
'3.1.1'

[screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYX1t.png)

[graph-saves-correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPEEf.png)

Comment: You forgot to show the actual error. So one cannot know why this code, that works fine, does not work for you.

Comment: Can you tell us on which line it fails specifically? Which function call causes the issue? You could comment everything and then uncomment every line until an error occurs on execution. Maybe there's a github page of this issue.

Comment: Sorry, if I wasn't clear. An error in python consists of much more than its last line. It usually starts with the word "Traceback" and is at least 3 lines long, sometimes rather some dozens of lines. Without this complete error one cannot know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us on which line it fails specifically? Which function call causes the issue? You could comment everything and then uncomment every line until an error occurs on execution. Maybe there's a github page of this issue.

My suspicion is, that it's the ax.set() call. Haven't seen that before and never used it. Maybe it's deprecated in mpl 3.1.1. Apparently, this error can occur, when you pass a parameter that the function doesn't know (xlabel,ylabel,title): [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550795/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-value-of-undefined/6550881#6550881)

As a test, try running this:

```py
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Data for plotting
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, s)


ax.set_ylabel('voltage (mV)')
ax.set_xlabel('time (s)')
ax.set_title('About as simple as it gets, folks')
ax.grid()

fig.savefig("test.png")
plt.show()
```

Comment: The code is copied from the documentation of matplotlib 3.1.1; so it's definitely working correctly in that version.

Comment: Yes @ImportanceOfBeingErnest -- the code also works on my other computer.

I some how broke the configuration on another server... should have been using docker :(

Comment: You can just uninstall matplotlib and reinstall the correct version. Otherwise mind my comment below the question.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest  Already tried uninstalling and reinstalling.

Comment: I am not sure why there is aggressive downvoting here. I am having the same problem. Just started yesterday, suspect it is something in VS Code for me. For sure mine breaks at the fix, ax = plt.subplots() line.

Comment: Fwiw, as I mentioned I suspected VS Code. I restarted and reloaded the insider's Python release in VS Code and it now works.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! Looks like VS Code is the common denominator!