# I have an issue with my ionic html code, It is giving error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0MYV.png)

[image]

```
    <ion-col size-sm="6" offset-sm="3">
      <ion-button
        type="submit"
        color="primary"
        expand="block"
        [disabled]="!f.valid || datesValid()"
      >
        Book!
      </ion-button>
    </ion-col>
```

> f.valid gives me an error.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550795/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-value-of-undefined)

Comment: What does your component typescript code look like?

Comment: Hey plz share your ts file. Generally speaking, you should avoid binding property to a method. Such a method gets called thousands of times due to change detection running, which is pretty suboptimal.

Comment: try to make `value` in your ts as `value : any `

Comment: initialize it, on the typescript file.