# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null at <anonymous>:7:70

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

ok so I found a scrip that deletes all videos out of playlists on Youtube

only problem is it seems to not work

Since I only know a bit of C++, I have no clue what could be the issue

Code:

```
setInterval(function () {
  if (document.querySelectorAll("#video-title")[0].textContent.includes("[Deleted video]") || document.querySelectorAll("#video-title")[0].textContent.includes("[Private video]")) {
    let deletedOrPrivateVid = document.querySelectorAll("#video-title")[0];
    deletedOrPrivateVid.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.lastElementChild.firstElementChild.children[1].firstElementChild.click();
  }

  document.querySelector('#primary button[aria-label="Action menu"]').click();

  var things = document.evaluate('//span[contains(text(),"Remove from")]', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);

  for (var i = 0; i < things.snapshotLength; i++) {
    things.snapshotItem(i).click();
  }
}, 1000);
```

here is a screenshot of the error

https://prnt.sc/w7av1k

Comment: This question is rather useless, while not providing the DOM which the script refers to. If you've already found the `F12` tools, just inspect the DOM and set breakpoints in the JS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550795/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-value-of-undefined)

Comment: This: "_document.querySelector('#primary button[aria-label="Action menu"]')_" returns `undefined`. Good luck.

Comment: That script might refer to a previous version of the YouTube GUI... and while there is no DOM or URL provided, it is impossible to answer in a reliable manner; it's not only dupe, but also lacks debugging details.