# Why is waffle showing as undefined when using hardhat

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethereum, hardhat

I have installed hardhat and forked mainnet using

```
npx hardhat node --fork https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/my-api-key
```

Now while developing a very simple test like:

```
const { expect, assert} = require("chai");
const { ethers, waffle } = require("hardhat")

describe("Read and write to the blockchain", () => {
    it('should send a transaction (swap a token)',  async function () {
        const [ownerSigner] = await ethers.getSigners()
        const mainNetForkUniswapRouter = new ethers.Contract(addressRouter, routerABI, ownerSigner);
        const amountOut = await getAmountOut()
        const myAddress = "0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266"

        const txSwap = await mainNetForkUniswapRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(
            amountIn, // amountIn
            amountOut, // amountOut
            [addressFrom, addressTo], // path
            myAddress, // address to
            Date.now() + 1000 + 60 + 5, // deadline
            {
                gasLimit: 200000,
                gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits("5.5", "gwei")
            }// gas
        );

        assert(txSwap.hash)

        console.log("The waffle")
        console.log(waffle)
        console.log("--- --- --- --- --- --- ---")

        const mainnetForkProvider = waffle.provider;
        const txReceipt = await mainnetForkProvider.getTransactionReceipt(txSwap.hash)

        console.log("")
        console.log("Swap tx")
        console.log(txSwap)
        console.log("")
        console.log("Tx Receipt")
        console.log(txReceipt)

    });
});
```

When running this test `with npx hardhat test` I am getting the following error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'provider')
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/sendSwapTx.js:84:44)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9)
      at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
```

The stacktrace points to line `const mainnetForkProvider = waffle.provider;`

It seems for some reason `waffle` is undefined but I cannot understand why because I am importing it at the top of the code.

Any help on how to fix this error?

Comment: run: `npm install -D @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle ethereum-waffle`
add this line to hardhat.config.js: `require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");` 

It works but I now get this warning: You have both ethereum-waffle and @nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers installed. They don't work correctly together, so please make sure you only use one.

We recommend you migrate to @nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers. Learn how to do it here: https://hardhat.org/migrate-from-waffle

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550795/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-value-of-undefined)

Answer (score 2):

[@user3358107](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3358107/user3358107) answered [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72928914/waffle-undefined-when-using-hardhat/75461805#comment128922925_72928914):

> add this line to `hardhat.config.js`:
>
> ```
> require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `const mainnetForkProvider = waffle.provider;` to:

```
const mainnetForkProvider = network.provider;
```

Surprised you didn't have to change receipt to:

```
const txReceipt = txSwap.wait();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these versions:

```
npm install --save-dev hardhat@^2.9.3 @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle@^2.0.0 ethereum-waffle@^3.0.0 chai@^4.2.0 @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers@^2.0.0 ethers@^5.0.0
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck